# Appending select list with items from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, select

I have an array that I would like to use as options in my select dropdown menu. When I run the code, it only appends the first item of that array, and I am not sure why.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Reporting.aspx/actionType',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{ reportType: "' + reportType + '" }',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r, re) {
                $.each(r, function () {
                    testList.push(r.d)
                })

                for (var i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {

                    $('#drpAction').append('<option>' + testList[0][i] + '</option>')

                }

                console.log(testList)
            },
            failure: function () {
                swal({
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'There was an error loading the data',
                    confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: what is in `testList` ?

Comment: pls show us the array-data. Your example look like its an multidimensional array

Comment: what does `testList.length` gives?

Comment: I've updated the code. it is an ajax post, so the the array testList is different depending on what is selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to loop through the items in `testList[0]`

```js
var testList = [[1,2,3]]

for (var i = 0; i < testList[0].length; i++) {
  $('#drpAction').append('<option>' + testList[0][i] + '</option>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drpAction"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looping through `testList.length` but using `testList[0][i]`.. try using `testList[i]` instead, like i did here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {
    $('#drpAction').append('<option>' + testList[i] + '</option>')
}
```

but, if the items you want to show are inside `testList[0]`, you have too loop through `testList[0].length` instead of testList.length, like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < testList[0].length; i++) {
    $('#drpAction').append('<option>' + testList[0][i] + '</option>')
}
```

---

if nothing of this is working, i have to see whats your `testList` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem `testList[0][i]`, you are looping against `testList` but you want to access to a list inside `testList[0]`

you should put the `i` between the first brackets

```
$('#drpAction').append('<option>' + testList[i] + '</option>')
```

or check for `testList[0].length`